# Question mark in knitr code getting quote marks

Tags: sweave, r, knitr

I'm trying to use question marks in a code block using knitr, but in the compiled pdf always puts quotes around it, so, for example

```
<<helpCode, eval=FALSE>>= 
?rnorm 
@
```

comes out as

```
'?'rnorm
```

Is there a way to keep this from happening?

Comment: Can't reproduce this; in RStudio with a default 'new sweave document' with your chunk added I end up with `> ?rnorm` as ouput...

Comment: @Thell you are probably using Sweave, and the OP is using `knitr`. BTW, I think this question is better to be posted on SO instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the chunk option `tidy=FALSE`.